# Can i dynamically add a Directive received from server?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I am creating a form which is created from a configuration/metadata. I want to render that form from server and serve the html and js file from the server.
How to connect these file to angular in client side?

example a whole component containing js and html files, or

just an html file along with corresponding js file containing function for html validation

Comment: give an example what you will get from server

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZfGWYCaOrsnDL3UspiSS?p=catalogue

this plunk contains the html, ideally that html will be created with some templating engine like Jade, this html i want to connect with that component.js. This html should be served from server

Comment: Do you want to 1) create view dynamically, like show form sometime or list some other time etc 2) use jade instead of html with angular 3) get HTML generated at server side like jsp, php etc

Comment: 2nd and 3rd. i can generate form with some metadata, instead of generating on client side i want it to be rendered and stored on server and when the user requests the form he gets the html and js of the form. templating engine can help me in generating the html. client side is angular.
How to acheive this?

Comment: It is very difficult. Angular is not built for that. You can use jade it will get converted to HTML during build time and sent to the client. May I know why you want to do that way

Comment: It will be really easy to help you if you give what is that metadata and what is the output you are expecting in the question. plnkr has so many details , you can take a simplest form and show here to get better idea.

Comment: i can just generate that form once and store it on the serve so that it can be served to multiple users without repeated generation steps

Comment: You can do all that logic at client side right, its faster and easier .